# Rails: comparison of Status with Status failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I need to fetch all current_user.friends statuses and then sort them by created_at.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :statuses
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

And in the controller:

```
def index
    @statuses = []
    current_user.friends.map{ |friend| friend.statuses.each { |status| @statuses << status } }
    current_user.statuses.each { |status| @statuses << status }

    @statuses.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
end
```

`current_user.friends` returns an array of objects `User`

`friend.statuses` returns an array of objects `Status`

Error:

```
comparison of Status with Status failed
app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:10:in `sort!'
app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

Comment: Not your core problem but walking all those associations will kill you by the sheer number of queries. Grabbing all friends and all their statuses and then sorting them in code can yield an ungodly number of queries, your performance is gonna drop rapidly. Why not just write a single SQL query that can fetch and sort all those records at once?

Comment: Thank you, I found an easy way and effective way: `Status.where(user_id: current_user.friends.map(&:id).insert(0, current_user.id)).all` what do you think?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a similar problem, solved with the to_i method, but can't explain why that happens.

```
@statuses.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at.to_i <=> a.created_at.to_i }
```

By the way, this sorts in the descending order. If you want ascending order is:

```
@statuses.sort! { |a,b| a.created_at.to_i <=> b.created_at.to_i }
```

Comment: "comparison of X with X failed" error is triggered by `nil` on either side of `<=>`. By adding `.to_i` conversion you've turned nils into 0s and that cured the thing.

Comment: nice! In my case it should be impossible to get `nil` in this part of the code.. maybe its a bug, I'll start logging it. Thanks!

Comment: Serge - you should put that as an answer, and it should be accepted, as it actually answers the title question...

Answer (score 13):

This error message appears when sort gets a nil returned from <=>. <=> can return -1, 0, 1, or nil, but sort cannot handle nil because it needs all the list elements to be comparable.

```
class A
  def <=>(other)
    nil
  end
end

[A.new, A.new].sort
#in `sort': comparison of A with A failed (ArgumentError)
#   from in `<main>'
```

One way to debug this kind of error is by checking if the return of your <=> is nil and raising an exception if it is.

```
@statuses.sort! do |a,b| 
  sort_ordering = b.created_at <=> a.created_at
  raise "a:#{a} b:#{b}" if sort_ordering.nil?
  sort_ordering
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem tonight on a group project. This answer didn't solve it, but what our issue was, someone put other models.new in our def show User controller. For instance...

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show

    @status = @user.statuses.new

end
```

This was creating a conflict between the @user.statuses and the @status I was trying to call on the page. I took off the user and just did...

```
def show

    @status = Status.new

end
```

And that did the trick for me.